# How to change name displayed when hovering over App Icon

Tags: cocoa, monomac

Ok, so I just created a project in MonoDevelop called Mac-Client. The project is part of a solution with multiple clients, which is why the app is named Mac-Client.

The problem presents itself when I run the actual client. If I hover the mouse over the app icon in the dock, it reads Mac-Client, and not what I entered as app name in the app.plist. I've also changed all references I could find to Mac-Client to Episode Next (name of the app)... What do I do to make it say Episode Next when I hover over the icon in the dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dock simply shows the name of the application-bundle.
In this case, Mac-Client.app is shown as Mac-Client.
This behavior cannot be influenced by editing the application plist.

For example, if you rename Safari.app to Firefox.app, it shows Firefox in the Dock.

The only way to display another title within the Dock, while preserving 
the application-bundle name, is editing the Dock plist-file located at:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

Change the file-label entry from 'Mac-Client' to 'Episode Next'.

In conclusion, better rename the bundle to 'Episode Next.app'.

Comment: Note that the plist file is binary; you need a special editor, e.g. [Property List Editor](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14363/plistedit-pro) (See  http://www.overclock.net/t/1153629/renaming-dock-icons)